# Strange behaviour during deployment of Jboss in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, deployment, jboss

I'm working in an app with:

- Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
- JBoss EAP 6.3
- Maven, Spring, Hibernate, Log4J etc...

I'm experiencing strange an strange issue when doing some modification in the code:

If I don't do execute <kbd>run as...</kbd> `maven install` with goals `clean package -X` nothing changes except debug points don't match with code. Build automatically is enabled.

- Why is this happening? Can be because `.class` files are not syncronized with `.java` ones?

Knowing this, it's a bit tricky but I can deal with it, every thime I make a modification, I stop the server, rebuild war file (<kbd>run as...</kbd> `maven install`) to see changes applied in the code and restart the server.

**Problem** comes randomly when I restart the server, app does not start and I get this exception:

> 17:40:12,816 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/xxx]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) JBWEB000287: **Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class net.aqualogy.xf.component.web.spring.ContextLoaderListener**: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: **Failed to load bean class: net.aqualogy.xxx.bc.impl.AClass**; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [net/aqualogy/xxxx/bc/impl/xxxxE_FCDImpl$2.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:291) [spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
>       ... 19 more
>   **17:40:16,998 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) JBWEB001103: Error detected during context /myApp start, will stop it**

In error log:

> **Publish Failed for module xxx-web**
>   eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
>   java.version=1.7.0_79
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
>   BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=es_ES
>   Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -perspective net.aqualogy.xf.tools.ide.ui.perspectives.XFPerspective
>   Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -perspective net.aqualogy.xf.tools.ide.ui.perspectives.XFPerspective

After breaking my mind for couple of days, I've found some strange things:

- If I remove the app from the server in Eclipse I still get same exception.
- If I try to clean server in Eclipse i get this exception:
  [image]
- After removing app, with server started, when I go to JBoss administration console, I still can see a war file deployed there.
- If I remove the app from the console problem does not fix.
- To make app work most part of the times I must perform:

  1. Run as maven custom install: `maven install` with goals `clean package -X`
  2. Remove app from server
  3. App and server clean.
  4. Exit Eclipse
  5. Delete manually maven repository folder
  6. Open Eclipse and wait till rebuilding workspace and download dependencies
  7. Add app to server again

I'm quite sure my server / maven configurations are wrong, but I can't figure out where to search.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is your server deployment configured? I would recommend to choose the option to publish in the JBoss deployments directory.

Comment: @simas_ch it's already deplyed in JBoss dir, i have custom configs in `standalone.xml` ...

Comment: Could you check Eclipse Error Log View and add java stacktrace to the question?

Comment: @dgolovin java stactrace was posted already, I updated question with the error log, but is same as exception....

Comment: @JordiCastilla, it is not full, there are NullPointerExceptions in screenshot, but not in log posted. Looks like you posted the title part of the log not actual content. You seems to have 3rd party tools installed and it fails for some reason, stacktrace would help to Identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project is up to date there is an option to update, right click on the project select maven > update project, then also make sure the project is cleaned, and run as maven as clean install.

Also I've always created a launch configuration with the options I want for maven launch

Comment: hi @snake, thanks for your reply, but if you read carefully you will se I have my own maven config, and I perform clean, update and installs several times and in several ways...